# Setting body background color in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a rather simple question about React, but I wanna see what the best practice is for this kind of situation.

How do you change the body background color, according to the page you are in? Do you set a CSS rule for the body background color in a CSS file for each page and import it in the component? Will the above work or do I need to add a CSS class to the body tag using componentDidMount, and remove it in componentWillUnmout?

Which one is the preferred way? I noticed that if you imported some CSS in one page, it will remain active even after you navigate to a new url. So, maybe I need to use componentDidMount/componentWillUnMount, is that correct?

Comment: You can import only the relevant CSS files in each component.

Comment: Do you mean for each route? React is an SPA (single page app), the content changes according to the route. What router are you using?

Comment: react-helmet will allow you to set body attributes at the component level within the jsx. Without helmet you will have to do it programmatically within componentDidMount. https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet

Comment: If you choose the programmatic solution, in componentDidMount: `document.body.style.background = '...';`.

Comment: @Osama I have updated my answer,did you check it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,we can change the `background-color` of `body` based on the route change.Determine the page you are in by using `componentWillReceiveProps` or `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method and get the route name using `props.location.pathname` provided by `react-router-dom`.If your route composes of `params`,then just replace the `props.location.pathname` by `props.match.params.customparam`

```
componentDidMount(){
 document.body.style.background = "red";
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
 if(this.props.location.pathname !== nextProps.location.pathname){
   const currentRoute = nextProps.location.pathname; 
    switch(currentRoute){
      case "\a":  document.body.style.background = "blue";
               break;
      case "\b":  document.body.style.background = "green";
               break;
      default : document.body.style.background = "red";

    }
 }
}
```